# How can I await multiple awaitables/IAsyncActions in C++/WinRT (`Promise.all` equivalent)?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt, c++-coroutine, cppwinrt

Is there an equivalent to JavaScript's [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in C++ or C++/WinRT for awaitables (or just [`Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.IAsyncAction?view=winrt-22000))?

For example, I am trying to gather multiple IAsyncActions and continue when all of them have completed. For now I'm starting each action and then awaiting them one by one in a simple loop:

```cpp
winrt::IAsyncAction AwaitMultiple(std::vector<winrt::IAsyncAction> actions)
{
    for (const auto& action : actions)
    {
        co_await action;
    }
}

// ... somewhere else...

winrt::IAsyncAction MyFunctionAsync()
{
    std::vector<winrt::IAsyncAction> actions{};
    actions.push_back(/* some function that generates an IAsyncAction */);
    actions.push_back(/* some function that generates an IAsyncAction */);
    actions.push_back(/* some function that generates an IAsyncAction */);
    // ... etc...

    co_await AwaitMultiple(actions);

    // ... do other stuff...
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is there a language way?

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Comment: WaitForMultipleObjects API

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can get a low-level Windows `HANDLE` to an `IAsyncAction` (or generic awaitable), which is my specific problem. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is often the case, there is indeed a C++/WinRT function for *almost* this case: [`winrt::when_all(T... async)`](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/4c7e2b5676f009cb336da77b96ab6069bfd17ff3/strings/base_coroutine_foundation.h#L820-L824) (it is not currently documented on [Advanced concurrency and asynchrony with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency-2)).

If you have modern C++/WinRT, you can await multiple actions at once:

```cpp
winrt::IAsyncAction MyFunctionAsync()
{
    const auto myAction = /* function that generates an IAsyncAction */;
    const auto myAction2 = /* function that generates an IAsyncAction */;
    const auto myAction3 = /* function that generates an IAsyncAction */;

    // magic!
    co_await winrt::when_all(myAction, myAction2, myAction3);
}
```

This is similar to [the Parallel Pattern Library (PPL) `when_all`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/task-parallelism-concurrency-runtime?view=msvc-170).

This doesn't solve the `std::vector<winrt::IAsyncAction>` above, but luckily Raymond Chen has some posts about that:

> A customer wanted to know how they could pass a std::vector of IAsyncAction objects to the when_all function.
>
> ```cpp
> std::vector<IAsyncAction> actions = get_actions();
> for (auto&& action : actions) co_await action;
> ```
>
> [... some more content about trying to wrap that in an overload for `winrt::when_all`...]

[Synthesizing a when_all coroutine from pieces you already have](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200902-00/?p=104155)

---

See also:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/news#new-when_all-and-when_any-async-helpers
- [Original PR for when_all](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/pull/516/files)
- More relevant Raymond Chen blog posts:

  - [Rough edges in the when_all coroutine, part 1: Empty parameter list](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200903-00/?p=104160)
  - [Rough edges in the when_all coroutine, part 2: Overloaded comma operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200904-00/?p=104172)

Comment: C++20 is currently lacking any sort of task support for coroutines. While C++/WinRT provides some support (as in this case), I frequently had to look elsewhere when it came to composing tasks. I usually went with Lewis Baker's [CppCoro](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro) (e.g. [`when_all`](https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro#when_all)). At that time I wasn't aware of `winrt::when_all`.

Comment: Oh, so your `std::vector<winrt::IAsyncAction>` have already been started and are executing in parallel when you get them, something I overlooked

Comment: @TomHuntington exactly! I view `IAsyncAction`s as handles to work that is already queued/executing. So awaiting them in an arbitrary order one-by-one is sufficient.